# How to replace such column names whose next columns are having all nan values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, file, file-manipulation

I have a file which has data separated with different spaces and column names are also having spaces.

```
Type Dec LookupTable               Field Name                Field Len Start Pos
NUM  0   _                         sample data               5         1
NUM  0   _                         sample data               10        6
CHAR 0   _                         sample data               60        16
NUM  0   _                         sample data               3         76
CHAR 0   _                         sample data               60        79
CHAR 0   _                         sample data               60        139
CHAR 0   _                         sample data               60        199
CHAR 0   _                         sample data               60        259
NUM  0   _                         sample data               3         319
CHAR 0   _                         sample data               60        322
CHAR 0   _                         sample data               60        382
NUM  0   _                         sample data               3         442
CHAR 0   _                         sample data               60        445
```

I am reading this file like this

```
df= pd.read_fwf('./temp.txt', colspecs= 'infer')
```

and getting the dataframe with columns which are separated by spaces nan values

I want to drop the  Nan columns and replace its previous columns name with the empty one.
How can we achieve this in an efficient way?
[image]

Expected outpuL:
[image: Expected Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

aaa = [(df.columns[i - 1], df.columns[i]) for i in range(1, len(df.columns)) if df[df.columns[i]].isna().all()]
bbb = dict(aaa)
df = df.drop(columns=np.array(aaa)[:, 1])
df.rename(columns=bbb, inplace=True)

print(df)
```

Here, in list comprehension `aaa`, paired tuples are created (on the `left` is the name of the column to be renamed, on the `right` is the name of the column to be deleted). Columns that are all with empty values are checked by the condition:

```
if df[df.columns[i]].isna().all()
```

A `dictionary` is created from `aaa`. `drop` removes the selected columns `np.array(aaa)[:, 1]` (to select an array by slice I wrap it with np.array).

Answer (score 0):

**I read the data from clipboard, so my DataFrame looks a little bit different than yours, that also means, you have to adjust the code, which shouldn't be a big deal**

```
df.drop(columns=['Start', 'Pos']).rename(columns={'Name': 'Superman', 'Type': 

'Mytype'})  # Very clear code, I think it doesn't need any explanation

df.dropna(axis=1,how='all').rename(columns={'Name': 'Superman', 'Type': 'Mytype'}) # the second way df.dropna(axis=1,how='all') means that it drops all columns with nans, but only if all of the values are nans.

    Type  Dec LookupTable   Field  Name  Field.1  Len  Start  Pos
0    NUM    0           _  sample  data        5    1    NaN  NaN
1    NUM    0           _  sample  data       10    6    NaN  NaN
2   CHAR    0           _  sample  data       60   16    NaN  NaN
3    NUM    0           _  sample  data        3   76    NaN  NaN
4   CHAR    0           _  sample  data       60   79    NaN  NaN
5   CHAR    0           _  sample  data       60  139    NaN  NaN
6   CHAR    0           _  sample  data       60  199    NaN  NaN
7   CHAR    0           _  sample  data       60  259    NaN  NaN
8    NUM    0           _  sample  data        3  319    NaN  NaN
9   CHAR    0           _  sample  data       60  322    NaN  NaN
10  CHAR    0           _  sample  data       60  382    NaN  NaN
11   NUM    0           _  sample  data        3  442    NaN  NaN
12  CHAR    0           _  sample  data       60  445    NaN  NaN

df.drop(columns=['Start', 'Pos']).rename(columns={'Name': 'Superman', 'Type': 'Mytype'})
#df.dropna(axis=1,how='all').rename(columns={'Name': 'Superman', 'Type': 'Mytype'})
Out[30]: 
   Mytype  Dec LookupTable   Field Superman  Field.1  Len
0     NUM    0           _  sample     data        5    1
1     NUM    0           _  sample     data       10    6
2    CHAR    0           _  sample     data       60   16
3     NUM    0           _  sample     data        3   76
4    CHAR    0           _  sample     data       60   79
5    CHAR    0           _  sample     data       60  139
6    CHAR    0           _  sample     data       60  199
7    CHAR    0           _  sample     data       60  259
8     NUM    0           _  sample     data        3  319
9    CHAR    0           _  sample     data       60  322
10   CHAR    0           _  sample     data       60  382
11    NUM    0           _  sample     data        3  442
12   CHAR    0           _  sample     data       60  445
```